# Frames formadas por outros htmls não estão aparecendo

Tags: html

Neste meu primeiro exercício de frames em HTML, criei um documento formado por duas frames em que cada uma é um outro documento HTML, que está na mesma pasta do documento inicial. O HTML das frames funcionam individualmente, mas ao colocá-los em frames e executar, nada acontece. Segue o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD> 
<TITLE>Aprendendo Frames</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<frameset rows="50%, 50%">
    <frame src="primeirohtml.htm" name="Parte superior">
    <frame src="SegundoHtml.htm" name="Parte inferior">
</frameset>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Está aprendendo uma coisa obsoleta que não se usa mais? Acho que não vale a pena.

Comment: Na verdade dvd, essa é a primeira aula, acho que só pra aprender os comandos básicos. Na terceira já vamos começar a ver html 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao contrário de uma página HTML comum, um frameset tem uma tag `frameset` no lugar da tag `body`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD> 
<TITLE>Aprendendo Frames</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<frameset rows="50%, 50%">
    <frame src="primeirohtml.htm" name="Parte superior">
    <frame src="SegundoHtml.htm" name="Parte inferior">
</frameset>
</HTML>
```

é interessante também definir o tipo de documento adequado, por exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```

É importante notar que desde o HTML5 `frame`, `frameset` e  `noframes` [se tornaram obsoletos](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features):

> Elements in the following list are entirely obsolete, and must not be
>   used by authors:
>
> [...]
>
> - frame
> - frameset
> - noframes
>
>   Either use `iframe` and CSS instead, or use server-side includes to generate complete pages with the various invariant parts merged in.